# IIS I/O operation error (Status 500)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis

I have web server running on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1.
There is IIS 7.5

I deployed API on this server. It's working fine in all browsers, but when I try to call it from mobile application every time i recieve timeout error. For API calls I use https and on server installed valid certificate.

I switched on failed request tracing and there was following error:

```
ModuleName    IIS Web Core    
Notification    1     
HttpStatus    500     
HttpReason    Internal Server Error     
HttpSubStatus    0     
ErrorCode    2147943395     
ConfigExceptionInfo         
Notification    BEGIN_REQUEST 
ErrorCode    The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. (0x800703e3)
```

Does anyone know what can cause this?
I'm 100% sure that mobile app requests are correct. I believe there is something wrong with server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably a [certificate issue](http://forums.iis.net/t/1188566.aspx?Client%20cert%20auth%20issue) or [Windows 2008 R2 Bug](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8e6c4b18-ba66-426a-93a3-1f1ff31d846e/wcf-net-40-iis-service-host-iis-error-result-code-500-error-2147943395-when-requesting?forum=wcf).